# $f(t) \ge 0$, $f'(t) < 0$, $f(t)$ is continuous, is it true that $\lim_{t \to \infty}f(t) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Given a continuous function $f(t): \mathbb{R}^{+} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that its first derivative exists and is negative, namely $f'(t) < 0$. Is it true that $f(t) \to 0$ as $t \to +\infty$?

In my intuition, it is true because the function is non-negative and it keeps decreasing. But I cannot come up with a formal proof of the argument. I appreciate any help.

Comment: If $f$ satisfies the hypotheses in question then $f+k$ ($k$ a positive constant) also satisfies it and thus the conclusion can't hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true in general. Take $f(t)=1+e^{-t}$, for instance.

Comment: More generally, if $f$ has the property then so does $f+const$ for any positive constant